# How to transform a String into an object name selectedItem in the DataGrid? flex3

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, selecteditem

I need to get the value of the item clicked and the name of the columns.

```
   for each(item in colunas) {

         var itemok:String = item.dataField;
         Alert.show(''+datagridlist.selectedItem.itemok); // show value of column

    }
```

**But this way it returns 'undefined'.**

But if I put the name already in function, I can get the correct data, example:

```
Alert.show(''+datagridlist.selectedItem.create); // create is a column name in mysql
```

But this variable must be created dynamically, example:

```
var itemok:String = item.dataField;
Alert.show(''+datagridlist.selectedItem.itemok); // show value of column
```

Could someone help me? I'm at it on time and I can not convert the string to column name.

I thank you all now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question already resolved

see as it was

```
Alert.show (''+ datagridlist.selectedItem [itemok]);
```

Thanks anyway to all and sorry for the two topics.

Answer (score 0):

Does your "selectedItem" Object contains a "create" property, or it is just the name of the table row?